# Google BigQuery basic questions

Tags: google-bigquery

These may be few basic questions.

1. When i load data into BQ tables, where exactly data stored? (If billing is already enabled). if it is data center, what would be data center capacity? Does our data co-exist with other users data?
2. When we fire queries, How our queries processed? What is the default compute engine used for this?
3. How can we increase query processing capacity?

Thanks
CP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. BigQuery datacenter capacity is practically unlimited. If you plan to upload petabytes in a very short time frame you might need to contact support first just to make sure, but for normal big loads everything should be fine.
2. BigQuery doesn't use compute engine, but a series of very large clusters where all queries run. That's the secret to a low cost per query, without ongoing costs per hour like other alternatives.
3. BigQuery increases the number of CPUs involved in your query elastically as the query needs. You don't need to manage storage nor processing capacity.

Comment: Thanks much for clarifying my questions. Could you please suggest BQ query best practices to get high through put involving fewer resources?

Comment: Depends on your situation. What have you tried so far?